# What is the meaning of "directed at bearing on" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> What Jim is saying is we may have all sorts of scientific accounts that involve something preceding
>   the Big Bang, or that the Big Bang occurred, as Jim was saying, in some larger arena, or something like that.
>   What none of this seems **directed at eventually bearing on**, and what I don’t see how it could eventually
>   be **directed at bearing on**, are questions like the one Jim was alluding to a minute ago, e.g., why there’s
>   something rather than nothing, or how it is that something that’s in some genuinely, philosophically
>   interesting sense nothing produces something?

What is the meaning of the bold parts? I searched the dictionary but couldn't find a meaningful meaning? Can anyone help?

Comment: “directed at bearing on” seems to mean “intended as being relevant to”, if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pick the phrase apart in order to understand it, because it's complex.

> to be directed at = to be intended to have an effect, or to be going in the direction of having an effect
>   to be directed at eventually = to be intended have an effect after some time
>   to bear on = to have relevance to
>
> to be directed to eventually bear on = to be intended to have some relevance after some time.

Jim is talking about some scientific accounts, but what he's saying does not seem to be intended to have any relevance to the questions at any time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

*Bear on X* means "to be relevant to".

The X in both instances of the phrase in your provided paragraph is "questions like the one Jim was alluding to a minute ago".

Comment: thank you very much but you didn't explain it thoroughly. you didn't explain the sentence and the "directed at" part. does it mean: scientific accounts that we are talking about are not relevant to questions like the one Jim was alluding to a minute ago?